# Vue 3 pass data in <slot>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

What I am trying to achieve:

Display an image from dynamic link in Post.vue, which follows the layout of PostLayout.vue


In PostLayout.vue, I have a <slot> named postFeaturedImage, and inside the slot, there is a <div>, I want to use the image as the background of it.

What I am using:
Laravel, InertiaJS, Vue 3

My codes are:


Post.vue:

```
<template>
    <PostLayout>
        <template #postfeaturedImage>
            <!-- Here I want to display the image -->
        </template>
    </PostLayout>
</template>

<script>
import PostLayout from '@/Layouts/PostLayout'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            featured_image: ''
        }
    },
    components: {
        PostLayout,
    },
    props: {
        post: Object /* Passed the prop from Controller */
    },
    mounted () {
        this.featured_image = this.post.featured_image
    }
}
</script>
```

PostLayout.vue:

```
<template>
    <slot name="postfeaturedImage" :bgImage="bgImage">
        <div :style="`background-image:url(${bgImage}); height: 75vh;`"></div>
    </slot>
    
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        
    }
</script>
```

I've removed all irrelevant codes. I am a beginner in Vue 3 and Inertia and in need of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach will be creating a `FeaturedImage` component. Also, you can reference the post image directly from the props you receiving. There's no need for the `data` method and the `mounted` in this case.

```html
<template>
   <PostLayout>
      <template #postfeaturedImage>
         <FeaturedImage :src="post.featured_image" />
      </template>
   </PostLayout>
</template>

<script>
import PostLayout from '@/Layouts/PostLayout'
import FeaturedImage from '@/Layouts/FeaturedImage'

export default {
   components: {
      PostLayout,
      FeaturedImage
   },
   props: {
      post: Object
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a props to your PostLayout.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    bgImage: { type: String },
  },
};
</script>
```

And give a value to that props in your Post.vue

```
<template>
    <PostLayout :bgImage="featured_image"> </PostLayout>
</template>
```

And if you ever want to have a post without an image and a different layout you should do :

```
<template>
    <PostLayout>
      <template #postfeaturedImage> post without background image</template>
    </PostLayout>
</template>
```